# AD get logged in user ip from username

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there a way to get logged in user's ip address from Active Directory with its username? (except Security Event Logs)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

No - AD is a pretty "static" repository of information about users and groups and computers.

But AD does **not** contain things like who is logged on and from what client machine. You'll have to look into server (management) API's or WMI or something like that.

Here's a link to a blog post showing how to use [WMI from PowerShell to grab the logged on users](http://www.peetersonline.nl/index.php/powershell/oneliner-get-logged-on-users-with-powershell/). Something like that might help you find out the logged in users